# #error "kernel version is not be supported. We need either mmput_async or kallsyms_lookup_name exported from kernel"

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04

I'm trying to install DCAP driver(version 1.41) for running SGX Application.My linux configured with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with kernal version 6.2.DCAP drivers are supported as inbuild versions(we need not to try installing driver for kernal version (>5.11).

In my case, i downgraded kernal version to 5.10.0-051000-generic. I am currently facing an issue after downgrading the kernel version from 6.2 to 5.10.0-051000-generic. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:

> #error "Kernel version is not supported. We need either mmput_async or kallsyms_lookup_name exported from kernel"

This error seems to suggest that the kernel version I downgraded to, is not compatible to install the DCAP driver(version 1.41), and it requires either mmput_async or kallsyms_lookup_name to be exported from the kernel.